# esp8266 immediately disconnect from server after establish connection

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266

I am having a bit of trouble here.

I get my esp-01 to connect to wifi and webservers, but with one website in particular it disconnects right after establish the connection (after type AT+CIPSTART), so i am not having enough time to write another command or post a request.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.franz95.000webhostapp.com",80

CONNECT

OK
CLOSED
```

I have also try modifying .htaccess setting keep alive connection..
Is there a way to make the connection duration longer before closing it??

Im using a esp-01
AT version:0.21.0.0
SDK version:0.9.5
SPI Flash Size : 4Mbit

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have no code, I am sending the commands through a serial monitor

Comment: The server's the one closing the connection. Nothing you can do about that. There's no website there yet.

Comment: `www.franz95.000webhostapp.com` and `franz95.000webhostapp.com` don't seem to be the same websites. And the server probably expects the request faster than a human can type.